# How to convert between date formats in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, date-formatting

I have a function ( named **test**) which return a date

I give you an example of this kind of return : **"01-Jun-2012"**

Now I want to make this date in this form   month/year

so "01-Jun-2012"  should became  **"06/2012"**

because  I want to use this Date to  send sms

```
send(To,Date) ->
Message =io_lib_format("pr%EAt %E0 payer le ~s",[Date]),
    Url = io_lib:format("http://192.168.1.8/sendsms?tel=~s&text=~s", [To, Message]),
     http:request(lists:flatten(Url), sms).
```

as I say the function **test** return a date for example in this form **"01-Jun-2012"**

an I should convert this form to another form  **month/year** ( as result to my example 06/2012)

I think I should develop a function which has as a parameter a Date in this form ( day-month-year) an as a result for this function a date in this form  month/year

note, I give you same example of date which should be convert :  02-Jan-2012  , 01-Feb-2012 ,01-Mar-2012 ,02-Apr-2012 , 01-May-2012 , 01-Jun-2012

as I say the function **test** return this kind of date ( in the code of **test** I execute http request in order to return this kind of date  day-month-year ( is a return of php script,

---

thanks , but when I test with ec_date:parse    I have this error    `** exception error: undefined function ec_date:parse/1`

note , that I work with version 13 of erlang

```
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
```

Comment: In order to use the ec_date module, you will want to add the file as a rebar dependency. Or just copy ec_date.erl from the linked repository to your own project's source code.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [ec_date in erlware_commons](https://github.com/erlware/erlware_commons), which is a fork of [dh_date](https://github.com/daleharvey/dh_date). (Both are perfectly valid, but I personally use the ec_date variant)/

They both can be used for exactly this purpose: parsing and formatting dates.

```
> OrigDate = "01-Jun-2012",
> ParsedDate = ec_date:parse(OrigDate),
> FinalDate = ec_date:format("m/Y",ParsedDate).
"06/2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `string:split/2`, `string:to_lower/1` and a function looking like:

```
month("jan") -> 1;
...
month("dec") -> 12.
```

should work. Also search github as there are probably date parsing modules for your format out there already... with tests.