# conversion of date in erlang

Tags: erlang

I developed a function in erlang which return date in this form for example: `15-Dec-2011`

I want to convert this date in order to became in this case `15-12-2011` (so `DEC` became `12`)

this is an example of date that should be converted

```
15-Dec-2011
19-Jan-2012
16-Feb-2012
15-Mar-2012
19-Apr-2012
17-May-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give basically the same answer with this post as the last post asking how to convert dates in erlang.

The easy solution is to use the ec_date or dh_date.

[convert date in erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177580/convert-date-in-erlang)

ec_date:format takes the format argument in a way similar to php's `date` function.