# date conversion in erlang

Tags: erlang

I developed this function :

```
get_data_by_transaction(TransactionCode)->

 Q = qlc:q([{X#transaction.datetime} || X <- mnesia:table(transaction),
                X#transaction.transaction_code =:= TransactionCode]),
    case do(Q) of
        [{K}] ->  
        {ok, K};

        [] ->
            {error, notfound}
    end.
```

when I test this function I have this result :

```
{ok,{{2013,3,6},{7,12,49}}}
```

my goal is to have this kind of result :

```
06/03/2013 7:12
```

so I should convert my data to be in the new format

can sameone help me to solve my problem

I try with this code :

```
format_date({{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, _}}) ->
    lists:flatten(
        io_lib:format("~2..0B/~2..0B/~4..0B ~B:~2..0B", [Day, Month, Year, Hour,Minute])).
```

and when I run this code I have :

```
3> format_date({{2013,3,6},{7,12,3}}).           
"06/03/2013 7:12"
```

**but my goal id not to display this result but to associate this result to a variable**

I will try to follow the links  which are in the previous response

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14179628/113848) help?

Answer (score 2):

If the desired output format is as simple as it looks from your example, an `io_lib:format/2` with the appropriate padding will do the trick:

```
format_date({{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, _}}) ->
    lists:flatten(
        io_lib:format("~2..0B/~2..0B/~4..0B ~B:~2..0B", [Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute])).
```

Apologies for the long line -- unfortunately, this is what you get with Erlang's format specifiers. If you want to learn more about them, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251869/how-to-format-a-number-with-padding-in-erlang) and the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2). Expect to return to this documentation every time you need to do something fancy with the formatting functions. It simply doesn't stick.

The call to `lists:flatten/1` is required because `io_lib:format/2` returns a nested list, presumably for performance reasons since the output will frequently be sent to functions that accept [iolists](http://dev.af83.com/2012/01/16/erlang-iolist.html).

Also note that before sending the tuple in your example to the function above, you'll need to get rid of the leading `ok`. Simply matching it as `{ok, DateTime} = get_data_by_transaction(...)` will get it done.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have this kind of result when I test your code :  "06/03/2013 7:12"
but I want to associate this result to a variable,